# Why does my app crash on my second activity?

Tags: android, crash

I am a starter in Android Studio.
My first app works just fine but when I select the home button it **crashes**.

Here is my HomeActivity.java:::

```
package com.example.ir_sensor;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Switch homeAwaySwitch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    homeAwaySwitch = homeAwaySwitch.findViewById(R.id.Switch_HomeAway);
}

public void switchChange (View v) {
    if (homeAwaySwitch.isChecked()) {
        homeAwaySwitch.setText("Home");
    } else if (!homeAwaySwitch.isChecked()) {
        homeAwaySwitch.setText("Away");
    }
}
}
```

Here is my activity_home.xml:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image_House"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/house_menu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:text="@string/location"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Image_House"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Image_House"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Image_House"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/Switch_HomeAway"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
    android:onClick="switchChange"
    android:text="Switch"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Image_House" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my LogCat:::

> 2019-08-18 19:42:54.636 15559-15559/com.example.ir_sensor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ir_sensor, PID: 15559
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ir_sensor/com.example.ir_sensor.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Switch.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Switch.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.ir_sensor.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:17)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Can you help me?

Comment: It should be only `homeAwaySwitch = findViewById(R.id.Switch_HomeAway);` .. Read what you have written do the basics..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `homeAwaySwitch` is to be assigned to the `Switch_HomeAway` ID of the context and not of the `homeAwaySwitch` activity.

Try this

```
homeAwaySwitch = findViewById(R.id.Switch_HomeAway)
```